# Video coversion using ffmpeg losing audio quality

Tags: video, ffmpeg

I am getting a bad audio quality while I am converting from wmv to mp4 using ffmpeg. My ffmpeg command is as follows:

```
ffmpeg -fflags +genpts+igndts -i "1.wmv" -c:v libx264 -preset fast -level 30 \
-qmin 38 -qmax 55 -movflags faststart -r:v 10 -vsync 2 -async 1 -map 0:v,0:a \
-map 0:a "1.mp4"
```

Can anybody suggest how can I convert the video without loosing any quality?

Comment: Next time when posting about ffmpeg command-line problems, please 1) post them on [SU] where they are on topic and 2) include the full, uncut command line output. I've voted to migrate your question.

Answer (score 2):

You haven't set any options for audio bitrate or quality, which means that ffmpeg will choose the best AAC encoder it is configured with (which will probably be `libvo-aacenc` or `libfaac`), and it'll choose a default audio bitrate.

Since you're converting something that's already compressed with a lossy codec, you'll lose even more quality.

Try setting the audio bitrate with `-b:a 192k` or higher. For LC-AAC, usually 128 kBit/s is enough, but if your source is compressed.

You may want to configure/compile your ffmpeg with `--enable-libfdk-aac` and use `-c:a libfdk_aac`, and use `-vbr 4` or even `-vbr 5`. Read the [AAC encoding guide](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Encode/AAC#fdk_vbr) for more.

So, for example, use this command. I do not recommend setting `qmin` and `qmax`, but instead you should use [CRF encoding](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Encode/H.264#crf). When you set `qmin` and `qmax`, you are constraining the video quality too much:

```
ffmpeg -i "1.wmv" -c:v libx264 -preset fast -level 30 -crf 23 \
-c:a aac -strict experimental -b:a 192k \
-movflags faststart \
-r:v 10 "1.mp4"
```

I assume you really want to reduce the video frame rate to 10 fps. If not, remove the `-r:v`. I removed the `flags` and `vsync`/`async` options, as I do not think they are strictly necessary for your command.

Comment: Hi slhck, Can you please tell me what be the full ffmpeg command after adding the -b:a 192k

Comment: See my updated answer. Note that I removed your additional `sync` and `fla g` options.

Answer (score 0):

Make your qmin to 10 and qmax to 38 and use -quality good. Qmin and Qmax are the ones which control your media quality. And you can also include 
-quality good in your command for better performance.

```
ffmpeg -fflags +genpts+igndts -i "1.wmv" -quality good -c:v libx264 -preset fast -level 30 \ -qmin 10 -qmax 38 -movflags faststart -r:v 10 -vsync 2 -async 1 -map 0:v,0:a \ -map 0:a "1.mp4"
```

Comment: The OP talks about audio quality, not video quality. And `-quality good` is not a valid option.

Comment: @slhck -quality good is a valid option i am using it for my project and its working fine.

Comment: There is a `-quality` option, but it is only valid for `libvpx` or `libwebp`. See `ffmpeg -h encoder=libvpx`. In the case of this question or even your command line, the option will have no effect, and it certainly does not increase the quality. (Especially not when `qmin` and `qmax` are set.)

Answer (score 0):

Although you can use the "copy" codec to avoid any loss in quality, I found that AAC encoding in FFmpeg sounded unusually terrible considering the bitrate.  The degradation of sound quality was very noticeable like what you'd hear in a 64k MP3.  I found that the flag  `-aac_coder twoloop` vastly improved the issue and resulted in normal sounding AAC audio for me, as mentioned here:

https://trac.ffmpeg.org/ticket/8066

Answer (score -1):

for a lossless conversion, set `-acodec copy`

Comment: If the input is a `.wmv` file, chances are good that you can't mux the audio stream into an MP4 container.

Answer (score -2):

```
ffmpeg -i source.mpg -sameq output.mp4
```

No need complicated code, Above will never compromise the quality.

Comment: -1, this is wrong. Please read: [sameq does not mean "same quality"](http://superuser.com/a/478550/48078). ffmpeg does not even have this option anymore. Also, the OP has problems with audio quality.